# How the Double Hash Function Works in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, hashtable, double-hashing

I was reading about HashTable and found a good source to easily understand [Here.](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~freedman/340/340notes/340hash.htm)

But I got confused on double hashing function. Here is the detail of double hashing function.

> Double hashing uses the idea of applying a second hash function to the
>   key when a collision occurs. The result of the second hash function
>   will be the number of positions form the point of collision to insert.
>
> There are a couple of requirements for the second function:
>
> ```
> it must never evaluate to 0
> must make sure that all cells can be probed
> ```
>
> A popular second hash function is: Hash2(key) = R - ( key % R ) where
>   R is a prime number that is smaller than the size of the table.

and Here is the Image of double hash function.

[image]

Now confusion starts. as they are saying in image. 49 should be on `7` positions from `[9]` index. then the actual position will be `[6]` then why they placed 49 at `[0]` index? and same for other remaining integer.

And what will happen when there will be no empty index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed image is **wrong**. Basic idea is to jump by no of places by value given by second has function, if already occupied, then keep jumping by same no. of places till an empty cell is found. For this to work, second hash function must NOT return 0.

For more explanation please see [here](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~cmoreno/ece250/2012-02-01--hash_tables.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The image is wrong, and might go with a different hashing method.

When there are no empty cells you'll have to *rehash*.  See the "Hashing with Rehashing" section below the double hashing section.

Comment: Ok thanks. and why Hashtable Searching is O(1)? I confused because some time we don't find the element from just one time then we need double-hashing or other to find the element then how it could be O(1)? O(1) mean find the element in direct like array?

Comment: @UnKnown The O(1) just means that the search time is roughly linear (independent of the size of the container).  The search in a hash table may take one or a few comparisons, but it won't take twice as long if it is twice as large.

Comment: For quadratic we also need rehashing? and when rehashing we need to use same index? or we need to pass index's value again from hash table?